# Location based AR

Tags: android

I am new for Augmented Reality though I know Android development.

I am trying to create an app whose main aim is to overlay the camera preview with some image if the device camera is pointing to a particular building or place. The camera preview will be overlaid with some image if and only if camera is pointing to correct building and correct direction. The overlay image & its related data will be uploaded from back-end. I have gone through mixar but it is not giving the correct solution.

In this I am not getting the Elevation / altitude concept. From where I will get this. Which opensource sdk is better for this app? How to crack this application?

Answer (score 0):

For altitude you should forget it. The altitude return by GPS is terrible. Just crossing from one side of the street to the other side, the altitude returned by GPS could be different by 50 meter. Also, the direction of the back camera using sensors will not be accurate enough for buildings close together. If you restrict your app for known buildings or places then you can adjust using some image recognition but still it is very hard.

Answer (score 0):

try to download `wikitude` sample app from `wikitude website`.it contain sample project `simpleArbrowser` that is what u are searching.hope this will help u

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any opensource sdk but I used Wikitude SDK which is quite useful for you implementation.The main advantage about wikitude sdk is that you can use your own server for back-end data. Which is not possible with the other alternative that is layar. And @Hoan is right about getting altitude information from GPS data is really inacurate but you can give it a go as the inaccuracy is only visible if you are really near the Point of Interest. It works okay for a distance greater than 250 meters or so(not confirmed). The only problem you might get is from the compass deflections which are really great when you are near a high EM field or near metals. But that's a chance you'd have to take and nothing can be done about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place AR objects based on the LAT and LONG of the location with a given altitude.
Well, now that's possible using Google's ARCore Geospatial API.

Docs:
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/geospatial